# Load a large DataFrame from Pandas to Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to load a huge DF into postgres table with `SqlAlchemy` but the process is always been killed after a while.
Is there a better way to do this with pandas?

```
...

>>engine = create_engine('postgresql://stargateuser:5tar9ate@localhost/stargate',encoding='utf-8', echo=True)

>>MainName.to_sql("landingpage_mainname", con=engine, if_exists="replace")
Killed
```

Comment: Have you tried the "chunksize" keyword? i.e. `MainName.to_sql("landingpage_mainname", con=engine, if_exists="replace", chunksize=100)`

Here's the doc for [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works! Thanks @JohnChing

```
MainName.to_sql("landingpage_mainname", con=engine,
                if_exists="replace", chunksize=200000)
```